# How to correctly inherit a class from sale module and change fields

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, odoo-10, odoo

I'm trying to inherit the "sale" module and work with my own product class. So I created this class:

```
class mymodule_product(models.Model):
    _name = "mymodule.product"
    _description = "mymodule Product Description"

    name = fields.Char('Description', required= True)
    code = fields.Integer('Code', required= True)
    category_id = fields.Many2one('mymodule.category','Category')
```

And I created another class that has the field that I want to add it to the sales order lines:

```
class mymoduleSaleOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.sale.order'   
    mymodule_product_id = fields.Many2one('mymodule.product', string='Products', required=True)
```

Then I created this xml code:

```
<record id="mymodule_sale_order_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mymodule.sale_order.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">mymodule.sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="replace">
                <field name="mymodule_product_id" />
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I added this code to **manifest**.py:

```
'depends': ['base', 'sale'],
```

When I upgrade my module I got this error:

```
File "..\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 380, in write
return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
File "..\odoo\models.py", line 3557, in write
self._write(old_vals)
File "..\odoo\models.py", line 3708, in _write
self._validate_fields(vals)
File "..\odoo\models.py", line 1079, in _validate_fields
raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `origin` does not exist

Error context:
View `mymodule.sale_order.form.view`
[view_id: 934, xml_id: n/a, model: mymodule.sale.order, parent_id: 539]
None" while parsing file:.../views/sale_order.xml:4, near
    <record id="mymodule_sale_order_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mymodule.sale_order.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">mymodule.sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="replace">
                <field name="mymodule_product_id"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

When I try this python code instead :

```
class mymoduleSaleOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.sale.order' 
    _inherit = 'sale.order'  
    mymodule_product_id = fields.Many2one('mymodule.product', string='Products', required=True)
```

I got this error:

```
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `randa_product_id` does not exist
```

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: I found my answer in your question :D

Comment: Good for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you well you want to create a new customized class of products and replace the old one in sale order lines. So, you have your `mymodule.product` class well defined, but you don't have to create a new class for sale orders nor sale order lines, just inherit from the existing one:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'   

    mymodule_product_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='mymodule.product',
        string='Products',
        required=True
    )
```

Then, your XML code must be like this one (I recommend you not to replace the original field `product_id`, just hide it. And I also recommend you to use `xpath` because there are several ocurrences of `product_id` field in the original view and if you don't, you're only going to modify the last one):

```
<record id="mymodule_sale_order_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mymodule.sale_order.form.view</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/form//field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/form//field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
            <field name="mymodule_product_id" />
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
            <field name="mymodule_product_id" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```